# Array, HashMap, Strings - how to send it via Bundle?

Tags: java, android

I know how to send simple array via Bundle but know I need to send something like this:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

How to send and retrive it via Bundle?

Comment: Sorry, what is a bundle?

Comment: You should prefer interface types (e.g. List, Map) to implementation types; you should encapsulate these in Objects other than data structures.  Bad encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayLists and HashMaps are serializable objects. So just use `Bundle#putSerializable(bundleKey, serializable)`.

If you want a more OOP approach, you can encapsulate the data to be sent into an object (say of type `SongData`) that implements `Parcelable`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) for an example. Also see the [reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for `Parcelable`:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
  private int mData;

  public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
  }

  public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      out.writeInt(mData);
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
      public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
          return new MyParcelable(in);
      }

      public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
          return new MyParcelable[size];
      }
  };

  private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is bad encapsulation, poor object oriented thinking.

It sounds like you need a `Song` abstraction so you can return a `List` of `Song` instances:

```
List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

I would avoid Java serialization; serialize them as JSON using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: I need to retrive file name and file path, so my thinking is ok. It have to be two-dimensional

Comment: No, it's not okay.  Those should be inside the Song abstraction.  File path on what machine?  More bad thinking.  A URL would be more RESTful.

Comment: local machine, exactly SDcard

Answer (score 1):

In the sender class

```
bundle.putSerializable("something", songsListData);
```

and in the receiver class

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)bundle.getSerializable("something");
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following in the sender

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
intent.putExtra("song_list", songsListData);
```

and than in the receiver class

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("song_list");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String str_json = gson.toJson(songsListData);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data",str_json);
```

Use Gson for  converting  arraylist data into string

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = gson.fromJson(data, type);
```

For  retrieving data in reciever class